# Divs with 2 columns in a vertical column

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to make a column with DIV's one after another, each DIV split into 2 columns..I've managed to do it but something tells me it's not exactly semantic...so if someone could take a look and tell me how to code it better?

http://jsfiddle.net/SynQp/1/

```
    <body>

        <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="lt">

        <div id="bl">
            <p>column 1</p>
        </div>

        <div id="br">
            <p>column 2</p>
        </div>

        <p><br>&nbsp;</p>

        <div id="bl">
            <p>column 1</p>
        </div>

        <div id="br">
            <p>column 2</p>
        </div>

         </div> 


        <div id="rt">
       <p>123</p>
        </div>

     </div>

    </body>
```

---

```
@import url("reset.css");

body {
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
color:#000;
}

#wrapper {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 960px;
padding: 4px;
background-color: #999;
height: 600px;
}

#lt {
background: #33CCFF;
width: 400px;
float: left;
background-color: #333;
height: 600px;
}

#rt {
float: left;
background: #FFFFFF;
width: 560px;
}

#bl{
float:left;
width:120px;
height:120px;
background:#fff333;
}
#br{
float:left;
width:280px;
background:#e4e4e4;
height: 120px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few improvements:

- instead of: `<p><br>&nbsp;</p>` use proper CSS-margins like: `margin-bottom: 20px;`
- you have multiple IDs with the same name, IDs must be unique, use classes instead!
- use semantic names: instead of `br` write `block-right`
- floats *can* be problematic, but they don't need to be. using `display: inline-block` may be an alternative

Comment: Additionally try to just not use any ids.   Force yourself to write classes and reuse their CSS.  Save ids for when you really need a unique sselection

Comment: Floats can be problematic but I wouldn't ever avoid them as suggested.  Just learn the caveats of floats.  Which is clear fixing

Comment: How can I replace IDs with classes? Does it make a big difference across browsers? Also, how should I name each class in this situation, should they be relative to wrapper or not? Jfiddle it if you want :D